# Error build application on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not able to run my application on iphone 4S (iOS 8.2)

The error message:

dyld: Library not loaded: @ rpath / SQLite.framework / SQLite
   Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E9BF12CA-EC41-4B75-AE57-B99197F8AF78/zeus.app/zeus
   Reason: image not found
(LLDB)

Comment: Any more info you can provide us with?